# Photoshop makes copie bigger or smaller when putting in a new file

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Photoshop makes copie bigger or smaller when putting in a new file

Don’t know why. I deleted photoshop - reinstalled

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the documents have different resolutions (PPI).

- High PPI image moved into a low PPI document means the image gets much larger.
- Low PPI image moved into a high PPI document means the image gets much smaller.